# Running a dbt snapshot model for the first time works, but on the second run, it executes indefinitely

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, amazon-emr, snapshot, dbt

I'm encountering an issue while running a snapshot on a table with over 1,000,000 rows, following the schema detailed here:

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyQ4q.png).

The initial run of the snapshot generates the table correctly. However, on the second execution, where the snapshot is expected to compare the data to generate updates, the execution never completes.

The table I'm transforming has a composite primary key consisting of 3 columns: 'document', 'change', and 'proposal'. I'm using these columns for the unique_key check, and check_cols to validate specific columns. Despite trying various approaches, I haven't found a solution yet. I'm unsure if the issue lies in the snapshot code or the dbt configuration.

Below is the code snippet for the snapshot:

```sql
{% snapshot snapshot_quiver_documentos %}

{{
    config(
      target_schema='data_lake_snapshot',
      unique_key='id_documento',
      strategy='check',
      check_cols=['grupo_hierarquico', 'cliente', 'documento', 'alteracao', 'calculo', 'proposta', 'proposta_cia', 'apolice', 'endosso', 'seguradora', 'produto', 'tipo_documento', 'tipo_endosso', 'nome_tipo_negocio', 'situacao', 'premio_liqdesc', 'adicional', 'premio', 'perc_comissao', 'perc_cocorret', 'data_proposta', 'data_inclusao', 'data_emissao', 'inicio_vigencia', 'termino_vigencia', 'data_entrada', 'data_cancel', 'tipo_emis', 'usuario', 'usuario2', 'premio_liqprop', 'premio_total' ],
      file_format='delta'
    )
}}

SELECT tabela_documentos.*,
       {{ dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['documento', 'alteracao', 'proposta']) }} AS id_documento
FROM {{ source('source_silver', 'fato_documentos_producao')}} tabela_documentos

{% endsnapshot %}
```

I've tried creating another column for a unique key and also attempted avoiding the use of an asterisk in the SELECT statement, specifying the names of all columns, but the issue persists. The snapshot needs to process correctly for tracking changes in this data source and creating a fact.

Comment: You can use [`dbt compile`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/compile) to capture the SQL that is being run on your database. Then, take a look at the SQL and even try running it yourself. You could put an `EXPLAIN` at the front of the query to see how your database intends to run it. This should help you figure out why the code is hanging. I see you tagged the question with `emr`, so also take a look at what is happening inside EMR when the query is running.

Comment: To debug, I'd start making sure that the unique_key `id_documento` is actually unique. The dbt docs mention that `Providing a non-unique key will result in unexpected snapshot results`. See docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/unique_key#description